# Given a user's SID, how do I get their userPrincipalName?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, active-directory, directoryservices

I have a list of user's security identifiers and I need to get a list of userPrincipalName's... is there any way that I can get it without loading up the users DirectoryEntry and pulling in the userPrincipalName property?

I need the most efficient method possible because this is done a lot

Answer (score 8):

If you're on .NET 3.5, check out this excellent MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx).

It shows the new enhanced search capabilities of .NET 3.5's `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace.

One nice feature is the `FindByIdentity` method, which allows you to find a user (or group) based on an identity - whether that's the user principal name, the distinguished name, a GUID or the SID - it'll just work :

```
UserPrincipal user = 
  UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext,
                               IdentityType.Sid, (value));
```

You need to make sure to provide the SID in the proper format - see the MSDN docs for details.

Once you have the user principal object, just get its user principal name:

```
if(user != null)
{ 
     string upn = user.UserPrincipalName;
}
```

The sample code for the article even has two additional helper methods `FindByIdentityGuid` and `FindByIdentitySid` to achieve exactly what you're looking for!

Go check it out and use it.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck on .Net 2.0, but it's good to know this exists for when we upgrade. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can get this using the [LookupAccountSid()](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.LookupAccountSid) method to call out to Win32. There is some sample code on the page I have linked to that shows a simple example.